# bootstrap 3 cover template in full width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi just would to know if anyone knows how to get the bootstrap 3 cover template in full width . I would like the header,content and footer area wider in order to, for example, have  the menu on the header completely to the right...would be even better if I achieve the cover template result using the simple bootstrap 3 template without the having to use the cover template, which I find a bit difficult to understand.
Anyone has an idea on how to achieve this, please?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can Replace the `container` class with `container-fluid` to get full width....